# RoR when use to_json function, how to package extra information in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Recently, I got a problem.

I wanna use Json form to transfer model information in Ruby on Rails. Original function will package all attributes in this model only. But this model have a sub-model. linked by has_many definition.

If I need to_json function could package sub-model attributes inside. What I can do?

Answer (score 2):

You could go for an alternative approach and use [JSON builder](https://github.com/dewski/json_builder) for example. Or just override the `to_json` method of the model you want to change the default behaviour of.

Comment: for more info you can watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl,http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

Answer (score 0):

To include/exclude properties in the JSON of an ActiveRecord model, override the `as_json` method.

```rb
def as_json(opts)
  super(opts).merge(
    "other_1" => "Some value",
    "other_2" => self.get_other_value
  )
end
```

Calling super will allow you include the standard JSON for all attributes, then merge on you additional attributes. Or just construct a Hash for the attributes.